# After Successful Login, this is not redirect to Homepage in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**When I put the correct username and password then my login page is not redirecting to home page. please tell what I'm doing wrong**

```
     <form id="formLogin" role="form" method="post" ng-submit="userlogin()">
      <div>
      <h4 class="mr-t20 mr-b30" hidden="" style="color:red;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">{{alertmessage}}</h4>
      </div>
       <div class="form-group inputWithIcon">
          <input placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" ng-model="logininfo.oe_email" name="oe_email" id="oe_email" class="form-control" required>
           <i style="font-size:15px;" class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
    <div class="form-group inputWithIcon">
            <input placeholder="Password" type="password" ng-model="logininfo.oe_password" name="oe_password" id="oe_password" class="form-control" required>
            <i style="font-size:20px;" class="fa fa-lock fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           </div>
         <div class="form-group lable-color">
      <span style="padding-left: 10px;"><input id="remember-me" name="remember-me" type="checkbox"></span><span style="padding-left: 8px;font-size: 11px;">Remember me</span> </label>
           <a class="lable-color" href="forgot_password.html" style="float: right;font-size: 11px;"><small>Forgot password?</small></a>
                                        </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 40px;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary custom">Login Now</button>
         <button href="Sign-up.html" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary custom1">Create account</button>
          </div>
</form>
```

**this is my Controller here also I want to user details after login**

```
$scope.userlogin = function () {

    $http.post(baseURL + "userLogin",$scope.logininfo).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

    function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        if (response.usernameexist === false) {
            $scope.alertmessage = data.message;
            $("#alertmessage").show("slow");
          } else {
            if($rootScope.passValid===true){
                $scope.loginSuccess = true;

                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.alertmessage = response.message;
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
                }, 3000);
              } else {
                $scope.alertmessage = response.message;
                $("#alertmessage").show("slow");
              }
              }
      };
      function errorCallback(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

on success to redirect use

> $location.path('/dashboard')

so that it redirects to the dashboard page

Answer (score 0):

Without know more about your application and desired results, there are a couple solutions you can try making:

First off, your currently have this below.  If you're executing this within your angular application, you should be doing `$window` instead of `window`, remember to inject it into your controller too.

```
window.location.href = "index.html";
```

Changed to:

```
$window.location.href = "index.html";
```

However if you're current Url is: `http://example.com/#/login` this will take you to `http://example.com/index.html` which might be outside of your AngularJS Context.  If you want to simply change the view being rendered in your AngularJS session, without performing a full reload of the page, you can do one of the following:

```
$window.location.href = "#/index.html";
```

or..

```
$location.path('/index.html');
```